# Handle thread abort exception in threads....?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Child thread is waiting for response from webserver, and is having a timeout value too. 
If timeout value comes first before getting response from web server, it will proceed to request timeout and thread abort exceptions. 
How do we handle this and log into a text file….? 
**Parent Thread**

```
  public void  Save()
 {
  List<Job> Jobs = PickJobs();

  int workerThreads = 0,compThreads = 0;
  ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(workerThreads, compThreads);

  int requiredThreads = 15;
  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(requiredThreads, compThreads);

  WaitCallback waitCallBack = default(WaitCallback);
  ManualResetEvent mEvent = default(ManualResetEvent);

 foreach (Job _job in Jobs) 
   {
   waitCallBack = new WaitCallback(CallBackFunc);
   mEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   events.Add(mEvent);
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallBack, new UrlData(_job, mEvent, HttpContext.Current));
   }
     WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray(), 300000);//05 Minutes
 }
```

**Child Threads**

```
private void CallBackFunc(object obj)
{
     UrlData msgObj = (UrlData)obj;
   WebRequest lWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(psUrl);
   lWebRequest.Timeout = 60000;
   WebResponse lWebResponse = lWebRequest.GetResponse;

    msgObj.FinishEvent.Set();
}
```

**Object for communication across threads**

```
public class UrlData
{
public Job job;
public ManualResetEvent FinishEvent;
public HttpContext HttpContextRef;

public UrlData(Job pJob, ManualResetEvent pEvent, HttpContext pContext)
  {
      job= pJob;
      FinishEvent = pEvent;
      HttpContextRef = pContext;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're asking how to log to a file if your child thread times out?

If so, I believe that the `GetResponse()` method throws `WebException` if the time out limit is reached before it receives a response. So surrounding the line where you make the `GetResponse()` call with a try-catch statement should allow you to log information to a file.

Example:

```
try {
    WebResponse lWebResponse = lWebRequest.GetResponse;
} catch (WebException ex) {
    // Write to file code in here
}
```

As `GetResponse()` is abstract the `WebException` is actually thrown by either the [FileWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.net.filewebrequest.getresponse.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) implementations of `GetResponse()`.